# OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: <PATH>:

Tags: linux, docker, gcloud, docker-container

I've created a astronomer airflow directory home\acoppers\astronomer. I ran docker db init and docker astro start to get my containers running. I want to authenticate my scheduler container to gcloud so I tried the command:

```
docker container exec -it 6903e8589b00 /home/acoppers/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud auth application-default login --no-launch-browser
```

Since I installed google-cloud-sdk in my home directory. However I am getting the following error when I run this command:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "/home/acoppers/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud": stat /home/acoppers/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Someone might find this useful. I was unable exec into the docker container like above. I got:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: 
starting container process caused: setup user: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Turned out - in my case - NodeJS child process caused **/dev/null** to disappear as soon as I restored it

```
mknod /dev/null c 1 3
chmod 666 /dev/null
```

I was able to log in again (tested with two shells one was in the other out)